# EF Core Loading One-To-One Entities Circular dependency

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create an API and I'm having difficulty with a One to One Relationship in EF Core 2.0. 
One `Person` Has to have One `Car`, and One `Car` has to have One `Person`.
I have two endpoints `/Person` and `/Car`.

When I perform a get request to `/Person` I get a list of all people, and those people have one car, but the car also has the details of the Person as well. E.g.

```
[{
    "id": 1
    "firstName": "name",
    "carId": 2
    "car" : {
        "id": 2,
        "make": "Ford",
        "person" : {
            "id": 1
            "firstName": "name",
            "carId": 2
        }
    }
}]
```

When I perform a get request to `/Car` I get a list of cars, and those cars have a person. E.g.

```
[{
    "id": 2,
    "make": "Ford",
    "person":{
        "id": 1
        "firstName": "name",
        "carId": 2
     }
}]
```

Here is the my model builder from my DbContext

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
    .HasKey(t => new { t.Id });

modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasKey(t => new { t.Id });

modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasOne(t => t.Car)
    .WithOne(m => m.Person)
    .HasForeignKey<Car>(f => f.PersonId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().ToTable("Person");

modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().ToTable("Car");
```

Here is the method I'm using to get each entity

```
return this.People
    .Include(m => m.Car)
    .ToList();

return this.Car
    .Include(m => m.Person)
    .ToList();
```

Here is my Person class:

```
public class Person
{                           
     [Required]
     public Guid id { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public string FirstName { get; set; }

     public Car Car { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Car Class:

```
public class Car
{                           
     [Required]
     public Guid id { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public string Make { get; set; }

     public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

So My question is: why does this happen for `/Person` and Not `/Car`?
and is there a way I can prevent it?

Comment: You could use `PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects` inside your `JsonSerializerSettings` object. This will keep your references while avoiding the serialization of duplicate objects. But, I strongly suggest you to return not the actual objects from your API, but to create surrogates with specifically the properties you want to expose (some call them DTOs, others ViewModels).

Comment: Thanks Federico!, I'll Try it. Yes, I have converted them to ViewModels using AutoMapper, (Not included in description) they are essentially copies of the model. The entities returned from my DbContext have a circular dependency, which is why the ViewModels have the same issue. I thought I'd ask about what I thought was the source of the problem though.